# How to place a button inside dynamic table in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

How to push a button to Array without knowing the DOM reference 
rowData.values will be place in table  the button is placed as string but i need an button its returning as string tried with renderer but no luck.

```
<detail-table 
 [header]="summary.table.header" 
 [data]="summary.table.data$">
```

```
buildTableData(sourceData, kind: number, flags): core.DetailRow[] {
 let tableData: core.DetailRow[] = [];
 let nodeIdx = sourceData.length;
   while (nodeIdx--) {
     const sourceDataRow = sourceData[nodeIdx];
       const rowData = {
         id: sourceDataRow.id[0],
         values: [
              sourceDataRow.description,
              sourceDataRow.name
          ]
      };
      if (kind === 1) {
         const contentString = '<button #myButton (click)="onClicked()">Click Here!</button>';
         rowData.values.push(contentString  + "(" +sourceDataRow.number+ ")");
      }
      tableData.push(rowData);
 }
    return tableData;}

onClicked(){
     console.log("button Clicked!");
}
```

Comment: can you provide a minimal reproducible solution in https://stackblitz.com/ ?

Answer (score 1):

The way you insert the button is not how angular should be used. Move the button in your  component html :

```
...
<button *ngIf="tableKind == 1" (click)="onClick.emit()">Click Here!</button>
...
```

`onClick` would be an @Output in your  component .ts.
Also `tableKind` will be passed as an input.

```
@Output() onClick: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
@Input() tableKind: number;
```

Then you will call `<detail-table>` like that :

```
<detail-table 
 [header]="summary.table.header" 
 [data]="summary.table.data$"
 [tableKind]="kind"
 (onClick)="onClicked()">
```